# TIdTCPClient ReadBytes does not reset the buffer

Tags: delphi, indy

I use a worker thread to read data with `TIdTCPClient`, as described in other articles. The thread gets the data with this command:

```
FClient.IOHandler.ReadBytes (FData,-1,False);
```

where `FClient` is the `TIdTCPClient` and `FData` is `TIdBytes`.

This is the reading thread's whole `Execute()` method:

```
procedure TReadingThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  if not assigned(FClient.IOHandler) then exit;
  while not terminated do
  begin
    if FClient.IOHandler <> nil then
    begin
      try
        FClient.IOHandler.ReadBytes (FData,-1,False);
        Synchronize(DataReceived);

        SetLength (FData,0);

      except
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

If I do not use `SetLength (FData,0)` then the next incoming data is appended to `FData`. I have never read about it in other discussions.

I am using Delphi RAD Studio 10.3.

Is this known that `FData` has to be set to 0, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is there any documentation for this method? If so, what does it say? If not, what does the source code say?

Comment: This should only append if the third argument `AAppend` is `True`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the contents of FData following the first read and then following a second read (omitting the `SetLength` call to zero).  I suspect the data is not actually being appended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `AByteCount` parameter to `-1` tells `ReadBytes()` to return whatever bytes are available at that moment, reading from the socket first if the `InputBuffer` is currently empty.

Setting the `AAppend` parameter to False tells `ReadBytes()` to use the `TIdBytes`' existing memory to read bytes into. If the length of the `TIdBytes` is shorter than the number of bytes being returned, the length is expanded accordingly. But, if the length is equal or larger, it is left untouched. This allows you to preallocate a buffer and reuse it without reallocating it on each read. But, this does mean that if the length is larger than the number of bytes being returned, any previous data in the unread portion is left untouched.

if you set the `AAppend` parameter to True instead, the returned bytes are appended to the very end of the `TIdBytes`' existing memory, leaving all previous data in the `TIdBytes` untouched.

Either way, if you want your `DataReceived()` method to receive a fresh `FData` containing just new bytes, you have to reset its length to 0 before each read.

Comment: This entirely explains the question. Thank you!